# JavaScript Tree issue on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I need some help with my JavaScript. My JavaScript code is not working on Internet Explorer 8, it gives a blank display,and some error code, on ie console, please suggest me some solution to get this JavaScript code working on Internet Explorer. The following is the link for the fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliparvez20/Ek2xS/47/)

---

Error Code

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
   File: treelist.js, Line: 12, Column: 13

---

```
var dataSource = {
            "Watch": {
                "Titan": {},
                "parent": {
                    "leaf1": {},
                    "leaf2": {}
                },
            }
        },
    traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                var classNames = e.currentTarget.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    e.currentTarget.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    e.currentTarget.className = e.currentTarget.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length) {
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
}
```

Comment: A general rule of thumb: if you have an error code or error message, include it with your question.

Comment: But it looks like the problem is you're using JavaScript features not present in IE8. Check out [this link](http://blog.patricktresp.de/2012/02/internet-explorer-8-and-all-the-fun-stuff-e-stoppropagation-e-preventdefault-mousedown/) for more info. You have this question tagged `jquery` but no jquery code. jQuery would be a reasonable solution to your problems, as it takes care of X-Browser troubles for you.

Comment: Error code is : SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
File: treelist.js, Line: 12, Column: 13

Comment: Please check this line of code `Object.keys(obj[prop]).length`. The error explicitly states that `Object` doesnot support properties/methods named "keys". So there must be some place in your code that extends `Object` with some method named "keys". But I dont find that in your code.

Comment: yes did check it, still not working on IE

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses `Object.keys()`, which is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 (support was introduced in IE9). [MDN has more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), including a polyfill you can use to fix your problem. Simply paste it into the relevant Javascript file.

As [Zach L](/users/363701/zach-l) pointed out, your code also uses `e.stopPropogation()`. This is also unsupported by IE8 (again, it was introduced in IE9). [MDN has more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation), and [Jonathan T. Neal has a polyfill](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/polyfills-and-prototypes/) you can use to work around the problem (it's the `addEventListener` code at the end of the article). Again, just paste it in.

Comment: his suggestion was to read the MDN article which includes all the info needed to solve your problem, including this link with an easy code snippet. http://tokenposts.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/javascript-objectkeys-browser.html Note that the `Object.keys()` is not the only thing in your code that is not IE8 compatible. Please look at [the article I posted in the comments above](http://blog.patricktresp.de/2012/02/internet-explorer-8-and-all-the-fun-stuff-e-stoppropagation-e-preventdefault-mousedown/) for info on `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @user3237973 I've reworded the answer. Is that better?

Comment: Thank you... i am checking it